# Setting the vertical distance in \overline

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes

I want to overline a piece of text, but the line is too close to the number, which is not nice, so I want to add some kind of padding between the overline and the text. This is what I've made up so far:

```
$\overline{\mbox{XXX\raisebox{0.8cm}{}}}$
```

where `XXX` is the text I want to overline.

This looks very ugly for me, so I was wondering whether there is any better way to do it.

Comment: probably `\overline{\strut XXX}` (or make a similar different strut if that isn't the correct spacing, but strut is used in other places to get even vertical spaces)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following example shows some alternatives.
Remarks:

- `\raisebox` can also be used to specify the final height (and depth). The height is known as `\height` that can be used for calculations (`\dimexpr` or package `calc`).
- `\vphantom`: placeholder for height and depth of the argument. The argument is not set and the width is zero.
- `\rule` with zero width can be used to insert an invisible vertical rule.
- `\strut` adds a invisible vertical box with height `.7\baselineskip` and depth `.3\baselineskip`.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ov}[1]{%
  $\m@th\overline{\mbox{#1}}$%
}
\newcommand*{\ovA}[1]{%
  $\m@th\overline{\mbox{#1}\raisebox{3mm}{}}$%
}
\newcommand*{\ovB}[1]{%
  $\m@th\overline{\mbox{#1\rule{0pt}{3mm}}}$%
}
\newcommand*{\ovC}[1]{%
  $\m@th\overline{\mbox{#1\strut}}$%
}
\newcommand*{\ovD}[1]{%
  $\m@th\overline{\mbox{#1\vphantom{\"A}}}$%
}
\newcommand*{\ovE}[1]{%
  $\m@th\overline{\raisebox{0pt}[1.2\height]{#1}}$%
}
\newcommand*{\ovF}[1]{%
  $\m@th\overline{\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+1mm\relax]{#1}}$%
  % Package `calc' can be used as alternative for `\dimexpr'.
}
\newcommand*{\ovG}[1]{%
  $\m@th\overline{\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+1mm\relax]{#1\vphantom{A}}}$%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}

\ov{XXX} \ov{xxx} \ov{\"A}

\ovA{XXX} \ovA{xxx} \ov{\"A} \qquad\verb|\raisebox{3mm}{}|

\ovB{XXX} \ovB{xxx} \ov{\"A} \qquad\verb|\rule{0pt}{3mm}{}|

\ovC{XXX} \ovC{xxx} \ov{\"A} \qquad\verb|\strut|

\ovD{XXX} \ovD{xxx} \ov{\"A} \qquad\verb|\vphantom{\"A}|

\ovE{XXX} \ovE{xxx} \ov{\"A} \qquad\verb|\raisebox{0pt}{1.2\height}|

\ovF{XXX} \ovF{xxx} \ov{\"A} \qquad\verb|\raisebox{0pt}{\height+1mm}|

\ovG{XXX} \ovG{xxx} \ov{\"A} \qquad\verb|\raisebox{0pt}{\height+1mm} + \vphantom{A}|

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Very nice list, for all kind of different needs. I actually went the `\strut` way, but the `\vphantom` method looks very nice for longer texts

Comment: I tried to use the second command with: `\begin{equation} \ovA{\rho_{0}} \end{equation}`, but I encounter the following problems `Extra }, or forgotten $. \ovA{\rho_{0}}` and `Bad math environment delimiter. \end{equation}`

Comment: @Antonio The argument of `\ovA` is set in *text* mode, for math the math mode setting needs to be added, e.g.: `\ovA{$\rho_{0}$}`.

Answer (score 8):

The separation is controlled by a font parameter, so it's a bit difficult to change it. You can add a predetermined height to the text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tolstrut}{%
  \vrule height\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`\A+.1ex\relax width 0pt\relax
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\textoverline}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{\overline{\mbox{\tolstrut#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\textoverline{no} \textoverline{with}
\end{document}
```

Play with the `0.1ex` dimension, trying various values until you're satisfied.

[image]

Comment: I have tried it but doesn't work at least in beamer. Increasing .1ex should rise up `\overline`?