# How to reduce the vertical space between two overlines?

Tags: spacing, accents

How can I move the top line closer to the bottom line (so that the two lines look like a cohesive adornment rather than two unrelated adornments) in `\overline{\overline{x}}`? I'm also interested in the analogous question for `\underline{\underline{x}}`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87609/82917: Not an exact duplicate but a closely related question (vertical spacing in `\overline`).

Comment: @campa: Thanks. However the question you linked to seems to deal with the vertical space between a letter and an overline, and not between two overlines. Additionally, that question seems to deal with increasing the vertical distance, rather than with decreasing it.

Comment: That's why I said "related" and not "duplicate" `:-)` And if you know how to increase a distance, by changing sign you can get a decrease...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. The following redefines `\overline` so that the new height (for purposes of e.g. adding additional `\overline`s) is increased by only 60% of what it would normally be increased by. I've done exactly the same thing for `\underline`.

To change the percentage from 60% to something else you can tweak the numbers `.6` and `.4` below. They should still add up to 1 though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\overlinewithoriginalheight\overline
\newcommand*\overlinewithlessheight[1]{{\mathpalette\overline@aux{#1}}}
%% N.B. extra {} is necessary for (mostly) proper superscript height
\newcommand*\overline@aux[2]{% %% #1 = \displaystyle etc., #2 = actual arg.
  \begingroup
    \count0=\fam %% Store the font (e.g. \mathbf)
    \setbox0=\hbox{$\m@th #1\fam=\count0 #2$}% %% just to measure #2
    \@tempdima=.4\ht0% %% Store 0.4 * height of #2
    \setbox0=\hbox{$\m@th #1\fam=\count0\overlinewithoriginalheight{#2}$}%
    \advance\@tempdima by .6\ht0% %% Add .6 * height of \overline{#2}
    \ht0=\@tempdima %% set ht of box 0 to .4 * ht(#2) + .6 * ht(\overline{#2})
    \usebox0% %% print box 0
  \endgroup%
}
\let\overline\overlinewithlessheight

\let\underlinewithoriginaldepth\underline
\newcommand*\underlinewithlessdepth[1]{{\mathpalette\underline@aux{#1}}}
\newcommand*\underline@aux[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \count0=\fam
    \setbox0=\hbox{$\m@th #1\fam=\count0 #2$}%
    \@tempdima=.4\dp0%
    \setbox0=\hbox{$\m@th #1\fam=\count0\underlinewithoriginaldepth{#2}$}%
    \advance\@tempdima by .6\dp0%
    \dp0=\@tempdima
    \usebox0%
  \endgroup%
}
\let\underline\underlinewithlessdepth
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
    \overline{\overline{X}}, \overline{\overline{\overline{X}}}
\]

\[
    \underline{\underline{X}}, \underline{\underline{\underline{X}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

A possible downside of this approach is that superscript height is also affected:

```
\fboxrule=.1pt\fboxsep=-.1pt
\fbox{$\overlinewithoriginalheight{X}^1\neq \overline{X}^1 \neq X^1$}

\fbox{$\underlinewithoriginaldepth{X}_2\neq \underline{X}_2 \neq X_2$}
```

From left to right: original, modified, without over-/underline:
[image]

If this is a problem you can use forego redefining `\overline` to `\overlinewithlessheight` (i.e., remove `\let\overline\overlinewithlessheight`) and use `\overlinewithlessheight` only for `\overline`s that are below other ones. (You may want to call it something else though, I'm bad at coming up with macro names.)
Like this:

```
\[
    \overline{\overlinewithlessheight{X}}
\]
```

**Edits:** bunch of fixes, and I originally forgot about `\underline`.

Comment: Thinking about it a little bit longer, I am actually a little bit worried about what would happen if the argument of \overline happens to use box0 for some other purpose. (Replacing 'X' by '\ht0=0pt\relax X' for instance breaks the entire thing.) Does anyone know a good way to guard against that?

Comment: (I think this is only a problem if the argument changes something about box0 without setting it first, which seems unlikely to happen. Still, I would like to know.)

Comment: I think the easiest way to overcome the problem is to define a new box.

Comment: @campa: Thanks, that'd work. I opted to instead store the height in a register.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see what the difference is between the original and the modified screenshots.

Comment: I've changed the image to make the difference a little more apparent. The difference is pretty small (and I think I may actually prefer the lower superscript).